# How can I clear the buffer in a C for loop?

Tags: c, struct, scanf

I am working on a school project involving structs and I am having the following problem:

I have created a struct that contains a maximum of 50 products.
The user will input FOR EACH product the INT code, FLOAT price, INT Quantity and CHAR name[256].

The problem that I am having is that the `scanf_s("%c", &product.name);` is overflowing with "\n".

Here is the code snippet:
[Lines 84 -> 88](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeQNx.png)

I hope that you understand my problem and that you can help me.

Comment: Edit your post to put relevant code right in the content.  And if it is a [mcve], it would be even better.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: You mean `getchar()`?

Comment: Perhaps you want something like `scanf("%s", product.name)` instead, where you read a *string* instead of a single character?

Comment: On looking at the linked "code snippet" .... off by one error.   Array indexing starts at zero, so the last element of an array with `n` elements has index `n-1`.   Your loop has array indexing starting at one.  Voting to close as this is essentially a (dumb) typo.

Comment: In `scanf_s("%c", &product.name);` the `%c` should *probably* be `%s`. But also Microsoft's `scanf_s` is **not** a direct replacement for `scanf`, and the call is missing one argument, which the compiler should have **warned** you about. You are using `scanf_s` with `%c` specifier incorrectly. *"Unlike `scanf` ... `scanf_s` ... requires the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or string control sets that are enclosed in []. The buffer size in characters is passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to the buffer or variable."*

Comment: Please do not post **images** of code. The commented-out lines in that image are not the same as the one quoted above, but the same applies: they both are missing a **length** argument for `scanf_s` which the compiler should warn you about.

Comment: use char *name instead of char name[256]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanf` has its place, but it is not the only way to read user input, especially when reading a line from `stdin`.  Consider use `fgets` to read these lines...

```
fgets(produse[contor].nume_produs, sizeof(produse[contor].nume_produs), stdin);
```

Will also work.

Here is some information on [differences and use cases](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-scanf-and-fgets/) of [fgets()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) and [scanf()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You should read with:

scanf("%s", name);

Answer (score 0):

You should use `%s` for scanning a string.
The `\0` will be added automatically at the end of the string.

Bear in mind that you only have 256 bytes for data and it will overflow if you want to add larger string.

`scanf('%s', obj.propertry);`

Since you added the C++ tag. Look at the `std::string` object and `std::cin`

`std::getline(std::cin, str);`

Comment: Two errors: `scanf` with the `%s` format will *not* add newlines to the strings; And you should never use the address-of operator `&` on strings. For arrays it will result in the wrong type for the argument, and for pointers it will point to the pointer and and `scanf` will write in the completely wrong location.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I've meant `\0`